# How do I use with PHP an XPath document object if I do not know his node-sets?

Tags: php, xpath, xquery, libcurl

How do I use an XPath document object if I do not know his node-sets? I'm scraping a remote web page by using Php support for libCurl:

```
$source = curlGet( "http://www.foo.com" );
function curlGet( $url ) {
  $ch = curl_init();        // Initialising

  // Setting cURL options
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USR_AGENT );
  $results = curl_exec( $ch ); // Executing cURL session
  curl_close( $ch );     // Closing cURL session
  return $results;
}

$domobject = returnXPathObject( $source );  

/* Function to return XPath object */
function returnXPathObject( $item ) {
// Instantiating a new DomDocument object
   $xmlPageDom = new DomDocument();
   //Loading the HTML from downloaded page
   @$xmlPageDom->loadHTML( $item );
   // Istantiating new XPath DOM object
   $xmlPageXPath = new DOMXPath( $xmlPageDom );
   // Returning XPath object
   echo $xmlPageXPath.'\n';
   return $xmlPageXPath;
}
```

Now, which nodes have been created starting from the remote page in the DOM object? I would like dump the contents of the object to an XML file. I'm sorry for this silly question.

Comment: Can you provide an example input document and the expected output, and where you're stuck exactly? I don't get what you're after, and what your problem is.

Comment: and, by the way, what is `$source`? i think you will need $xmlPageDom later

Comment: Input document is whatever HTML web page whereas I don't know the expected output because my goal is to determine it and dump it to file.

Comment: How do you want to navigate using XPath a structure you know nothing about? This makes no sense and currently, your question is unclear. You should improve your question so that we are able to help you.